# Combinatoric Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the correct way to solve the following question:
Jacob's bag has 5 pens: 1 red, 2 green, and 2 black pens. He takes out 3 pens randomly from the bag and does not return them. 
What is the probability of him taking out 3 pens, which all have different colors?

Comment: It will be P(choosing 1 red from 1 red,1 green from 2 greens, 1 black from 2 blacks/choosing 3 pens from 5 pens) = (1C1*2C1*2C1/5C3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of ways to take out three pens, each of a different color, is
$
\binom{1}{1} \cdot \binom{2}{1} \cdot \binom{2}{1} = 4
$. The number of ways to take out three pens from a collection of five is $\binom{5}{3} = 10$. So the probability that three pens, each of a different color, are selected is $\frac{4}{10}$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach that might be more intuitive for some people:
What are the possible sequences of selection that are acceptable for the problem and the probability of each?  They are:

1) Red - Green - Black:    P = 1/5 * 2/4 * 2/3   = 4/60
2) Red - Black - Green:    P = 1/5 * 2/4 * 2/3   = 4/60
3) Green - Black - Red:    P = 2/5 * 2/4 * 1/3   = 4/60
4) Green - Red - Black:    P = 2/5 * 1/4 * 2/3   = 4/60
5) Black - Green - Red:    P = 2/5 * 2/4 * 1/3   = 4/60
6) Black - Red - Green:    P = 2/5 * 1/4 * 2/3   = 4/60

The total probability then is 6*(4/60) or 4/10.  I hope this helps.

Comment: This does help, thanks a lot!